# StaticText appears too late

Tags: wxpython

I have a script which shall copy a big file (>100MB). This copying takes ~ 2seconds, so I want display a text ('start') *before* copying begins and another text ('end') when copying is finished. This is my code:

```
def copy(self,event):
    wx.StaticText(self.startpanel, -1, 'start', (80,110))
    if not(os.path.exists(path2)):
        os.mkdir(path2)
    shutil.copy(path1+'/test.zip',path2+'/test.zip')
    wx.StaticText(self.startpanel, -1, 'end', (80,150))
```

problem: when event *copy* is called, then nothing is displayed on my panel for 2 seconds and after these 2 seconds (when copy is complete) both StaticTexts appear at the same time!
Why does my first StaticText not appear before copying the zip-file and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking your GUI thread by long running task in event handler. You should use multi-threading. See description [**here**](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks). Also [`wx.lib.delayedresult`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.delayedresult-module.html) library is very useful.

So basically my solution would be: Set your label to "start" and start worker tread using `wx.lib.delayedresult`. Worker thread should copy the file. When it finishes, the consumer function is going to be called. You set your label to "end" in the consumer function.